# Why did my PHP API stop working and do no longer return a json?

Tags: php, json, get, http-headers

A few years ago I created a backend (PHP to get some data as JSON) for some of my mobile applications. I didn't touch this code since then. Now it stopped working some weeks ago. I am not a backend dev, so I have not much experience here, but few years ago I thought it would be better to create my own backend instead of using Firebase/Serverless...not my best idea :)

What did I try:

- check URL with Chrome --> everything works fine (I can see my JSON data)
- check inside apps or in Postman: (Header: Content-Type text/html)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<title>One moment, please...</title>
<style>
body {
    background: #F6F7F8;
    color: #303131;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-top: 45vh;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Please wait while your request is being verified...</h1>
<form id="wsidchk-form" style="display:none;" action="/z0f76a1d14fd21a8fb5fd0d03e0fdc3d3cedae52f" method="get">
<input type="hidden" id="wsidchk" name="wsidchk"/>
</form>
<script>
(function(){
    var west=+((+!+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+[])),
        east=+((+!+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!+[]+[])+(+![])+(+!+[]+!![]+[])+(+!+[]+!![])+(+!+[]+!![]+!![]+[])),
        x=function(){try{return !!window.addEventListener;}catch(e){return !!0;} },
        y=function(y,z){x() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",y,z) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",y);};
    y(function(){
        document.getElementById('wsidchk').value = west + east;
        document.getElementById('wsidchk-form').submit();
    }, false);
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my PHP file:

```
$response = array();

function saveResultOfQueryToArray($result){
  global $response;
  $response['workouts'] = array();

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

      $temp = array();

      //  $temp['aufruf'] = $aufruf;
      $temp['error'] = false;
      $temp['workoutname'] = $row['workoutname'];          
      $temp['duration'] = $row['duration'];          
      ...    

      array_push($response['workouts'],$temp);

  }
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {
  $db = new DbOperation();
  $users = $db->getHighestRatingWith31Results();
  saveResultOfQueryToArray($users, $chooseMethod);
}
else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong/what could have changed?

Comment: We will need to see the code for the functions you are calling, as they are not vanilla PHP

Comment: what gives `var_dump($response);` ?

Comment: Your `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {` part of the IF/ELSE does nto seem to place anything into `$response` ? Is the intension to only return a value if there is an error

Comment: I updated my code. I forgot to paste the function saveResultOfQueryToArray($result). My fault...  So the the $response is not empty and is working as expected (at least if I open the URL on a webbrowser)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')` has no `$response`. Unless there's more to the code, `$response` is undefined.

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET') {
  $db = new DbOperation();
  $users = $db->getHighestRatingWith31Results();
  saveResultOfQueryToArray($users, $chooseMethod);
  $response['error'] = false;
  $response['message'] = 'Whatever you want returned here.';
else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Something like that should do the trick!  I'd also advise looking into HTTP responses, like HTTP 405.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405

EDIT:  So I see your update, and I'm sorry, but it raises further questions.  Namely, what does `$db->getHighestRatingWith31Results();` do?  The function `saveResultOfQueryToArray()` accepts one argument, but the usage is giving the function two arguments?  The saveResultOfQueryToArray is calling mysqli_fetch_array(), which expects a mysqli_result instance.

Here's what I would recommend:

- Use PDO instead of mysqli.  I know you said this was old code, but PDO is fantastic.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo and https://phpdelusions.net/pdo
- I probably wouldn't make $response a global var.  I'd either return $response from `saveResultOfQueryToArray()` or look into passing by reference.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php
- Again, I'd suggest looking into HTTP response codes.
- Finally, and this is hard, I know, but name your vars something a little easier to understand and document your code with comments.  An old joke in computer science goes "The two hardest parts of computer science is cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors."
  "Documentation is a love letter that you write to your future self." - Damian Conway

Comment: Updated my code and added the missing function. Sorry my fault.

Comment: No need to be sorry.  "Experience is the name we give to our mistakes."  -Oscar Wilde